# eMMC partitions corrupted

Tags: htc, partitions, internal-sd

I flashed SailFish OS port for my device (HTC Desire z(Vision),S-OFF, rooted), after that recovery(TWRP 2.6.3.0) showed me that it couldn't mount /system and /data partitions and reported no OS installed. I initially thought maybe the SailFish repartitioned the emmc but it was not the case. All partitions are still present in /dev/block/. I tried  inspecting them with various tools but they all fail with more or less the same message.

```
fdisk -u /dev/block/mmcblk0

fdisk: can't read from /dev/block/mmcblk0


parted /dev/block/mmcblk0 print

Error: /dev/block/mmcblk0: unrecognised disk label
```

I'm running out of ideas. Is there a way I could force format the eMMC and then recreate partitions? Since the phone worked like a charm until I tried to flash it and I have a working Hboot and Recovery, I don't believe it's a hardware failure and dmesg doesn't show any frightening errors in that regard also.

EDIT:
Well i bricked the phone completely a few days ago, but i have some news if anyone encounters the same problem. It seems that when booted to recovery the phone tries to mount broken partitions and eMMC freaks out so you cant access anything on it. I ended up installing a CM ROM on the SD Card, and booting the phone with fastboot. eMMC partitions that didn't get corrupted can be read and written to with dd, and if you are fine with not being able to mount SD card as USB storage i suggest you leave it as is because everything else is working like a charm.

Comment: Check if http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23044/discussion-between-rjt-rockx-and-darren helps.